# Are you allowed to use portals in class or activity diagrams?

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram, activity-diagram

Especially in activity diagrams you sometimes have many different lines go back to the same starting point. It can get really messy if you try to route them around the rest of the diagram. So my question is, are you allowed to use portals with different colors where arrows go in on one side and out of the other side to make the diagram look much more clean?

Comment: `Portal` is not a UML term. Can you maybe add a picture of what you mean? That would make things a lot clearer.

Answer (score 2):

[Portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_(video_game)) is a fascinating game, where one can jump into a hole on one wall, and land at the exit from another hole somewhere else, the two holes together being connected via a portal.

I recognize in your terminology what UML calls an ***ActivityEdge connector***. Yes it exists, but it has some constraints and cannot be used exactly as you intend:

> ***(UML 2.5 specifications, page 378)***: An ActivityEdge may also be notated using a connector, which is a small circle with the name of the edge in it. This is purely notational. It does not affect the underlying model. The circles and lines involved map to a single ActivityEdge in the model. Every connector with a given label **must be paired with exactly one other with the same label** on the same Activity diagram. **One connector must have exactly one incoming edge and the other exactly one outgoing edge, each with the same type of flow**, object or control.

[image]

In other words, this graphical notation is just a way to interrupt visually one edge and continue it somewhere else in the same diagram:

- It is mainly used to avoid too many crossing lines that make it difficult to follow a flow.
- If you want plenty of incoming/outgoing edges, you cannot use the connector directly, and either you'll have plenty of connector pairs,  or for example precede/follow the connector with a merge/decision node (if this is the semantic that you intend).